# Send email with memorystream attached

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy, indy10

I am trying to send email with memorystream attached but I always got this message in the email I received and no attachment **"This is a multi-part message in MIME format..."**

Code:

```
var
  MemStrm : TMemoryStream;
begin
  MemStrm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Str1.SaveToStream(MemStrm);
  MemStrm.Position := 0;

  try
  with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 do
  begin
    Destination            := 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com' + ':' + IntToStr(465);
    Host                   := 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
    MaxLineAction          := maException;
    Port                   := 465;
    SSLOptions.Method      := sslvTLSv1;
    SSLOptions.Mode        := sslmUnassigned;
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode  := [];
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
  end;
  with IdSMTP1 do
  begin
    IOHandler          := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    Host               := 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
    Port               := 465;
    AuthType           := satDefault;
    Password           := 'password';
    Username           := 'sender@yahoo.com';
    UseTLS             := utUseImplicitTLS;
  end;
  with IdMessage1 do
  begin

    From.Address              := 'sender@yahoo.com';

    List:= Recipients.Add;
    List.Address:=  'receiver@yahoo.com';
    Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'receiver@yahoo.com';
    Subject                   := 'test';
    Body.Text                 := 'test';
    ContentType               := 'text/plain';

    IdAttachment := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts,MemStrm);
    IdAttachment.ContentType := 'text/plain';
    IdAttachment.FileName := 'attached.txt';
  end;
  finally
    idsmtp1.Connect;
    idsmtp1.Send(idmessage1);
    idsmtp1.Disconnect;
    MemStrm.Free;
  end;
end
```

I do not want to save it as file first then attach it, how do I attach the sample memorystream to my email?

EDIT: It didn't work even with TIdAttachmentFile, i'm using Indy10 version 10.6.0.5049 on delphi 7

Comment: Which Indy version is it? (Current is 10.6.1 iirc)

Comment: delphi 7 indy10 version 10.6.0.5049, just updated my question, it doesnt work even with TIdAttachmentFile, same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the top-level `TIdMessage.ContentType` to `text/plain`, which tells the reader to interpret the *entire email* as plain text. You need to set that property to `multipart/mixed` instead, then the reader will interpret the attachment:

```
with IdMessage1 do
begin
  ...
  ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
end;
```

I would also suggest you add a `TIdText` object to let the reader know what the email is about, eg:

```
IdText := TIdText.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, nil);
IdText.ContentType := 'text/plain';
IdText.Body.Text := 'here is an attachment for you.';

IdAttachment := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts,MemStrm);
IdAttachment.ContentType := 'text/plain';
IdAttachment.FileName := 'attached.txt';
```

Also, you are filling in the `Recipients` property twice. Use either `Recipients.Add.Address` or `Recipients.EMailAddresses`, do not use both:

```
with IdMessage1 do
begin
  ...
  List:= Recipients.Add;
  List.Address := 'receiver@yahoo.com';
  ...
end;
```

```
with IdMessage1 do
begin
  ...
  Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'receiver@yahoo.com';
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the ContentType definition of IdAttachment. 
You have to set it to `'application/x-zip-compressed'` like this:

```
IdAttachment := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts,MemStrm);
IdAttachment.ContentType := 'application/x-zip-compressed';
IdAttachment.FileName := 'attached.txt';
```

Comment: This is the wrong answer. You are trying to fix the error using the wrong value for the wrong property.